# Multiple Django app using nginx and gunicorn on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I am new to server configuration. I do some google and config django app using gunicorn and nginx on ubuntu 14.04 trusty server. For the first django app I use port number 80 and my configfiles are :

/etc/init/gunicorn.conf :-

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
setuid 
setgid www-data
chdir /home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject
exec /home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

My nginx configuration file for first django app:

/etc/nginx/site-available :-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

After that, i link site to site-enabled .
Next, i create a new django app inside the first django app virtualenv like:

FirstApp_Virtual_Env\first_djangoapp\app files

FirstApp_Virtual_Env\Second_djangoapp\app files

Now i configure gunicorn for second app like :

/etc/init/gunicorn_t :-

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject2"
    start on runlevel [2345]
    stop on runlevel [!2345]
    respawn
    setuid 
    setgid www-data
    chdir /home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject2
    exec /home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject2/myproject2.sock myproject2.wsgi:application
```

My nginx configuration file for second django app:

/etc/nginx/site-available :-

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name myapp2.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject2;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myserver/my_virtualenv_path/myproject2/myproject2.sock;
    }
}
```

After that i link site to site-enabled .

Now here is my problem: when i type myapp.com then my first django app is working fine but for second app when i type myapp2.com its showing nginx page and when i type myapp2.com:8000 it's working fine . I do some google for that but i am unable to find solution. I am newbie to this so please give me a hint for that how to correct my problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured nginx to serve myapp2.com on port 8000:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name myapp2.com;
    # ...
}
```

so why would you expect nginx to serve it on port 80 ?

[edit] I thought the above was enough to make the problem clear but obviously not, so let's start again:

You configured nginx to serve myapp2.com on port 8000 (the `listen 8000;` line in your conf, so nginx do what you asked for: it serves myapp2.com on port 8000.

If you want nginx to serve myapp2.com on port 80 (which is the implied default port for http so you don't have to specify it explicitely in your url - IOW 'http://myapp2.com/' is a shortcut for 'http://myapp2.com:80/'), all you have to do is to configure nginx to serve it on port 80 just like you did for 'myapp.com': replace `listen 8000;` by `listen 80;`.

Comment: i did not except myapp2.com on port 80 . When i type myapp2.com it show me the nginx config page besides myapp2.com. Thanks for response

Comment: "http://myapp2.com" is a shortcut for "http://myapp2.com:80". What do you think the `listen 8000;` and `listen 80;` lines mean ?

Comment: I am new to this but Is that possible two django app can share same port ??

Comment: for me listen 8000; means when i type myapp2.com it listen port number 8000 and listen 80; means myapp.com it listen port 80 ....

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django, it's a nginx feature (actually a feature of almost all http servers except some special dedicated ones). It's usually knowns as "vhosts" ("virtual hosts") but in nginx this feature is known as "server blocks" and is documented here https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: "for me listen 8000; means when i type myapp2.com it listen port number 8000" => nope, it means "listen to port 8000 and if ON THAT PORT you get 'myapp2.com' as domain name apply the following rules". It's the client that asks for a specific port (defaulting to port 80 when none is specified).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't type in a port, your client will automatically use port 80.

Typing `myapp2.com` is the same as typing `myapp2.com:80`

But `myapp2.com` is not running on port 80, it's running on port 8000.

When you go into production it is possible to redirect `myapp2.com` to port 8000 without explicitly typing it. You register myapp2.com with a [DNS name server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) and point it towards `myapp2.com:8000`

Comment: Sorry for late reply but when i type myapp.com my first app on port 80 is working fine but when i type myapp2.com its show me nginx config page. but whe i type myapp2.com:8000 its working

Comment: What happens if you try and just run both on port 80?

Comment: but how to run both on same port can u please give some example .....thanks for your time @jwillis0720

Comment: replace  `listen 8000;` with `listen 80` on myapp2 configuration file